# Async image loading from url inside a UITableView cell - wrong image while scrolling

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitableview

I had an IPhone application in which i am loading images asynchronously from an array ,using this in cellforrowatindexpath,

```
 `   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    sCell *cell = (sCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[sCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }
     NSMutableDictionary *dicttable=[sarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
            NSString *icon= [dicttable objectForKey:@"thumb_image"];

            cell.image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"thumbnail-default.png"];
            if(icon.length!=0)
            {
                if(![[ImageCache sharedImageCache] hasImageWithKey:icon])

                {   cell.image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"thumbnail-default.png"];
                    NSArray *myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:cell.image,icon,@"thumbnail-default.png",[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO],nil];
                    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate  *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
                    [appDelegate performSelectorInBackground:@selector(updateImageViewInBackground:) withObject:myArray];

                }
                else
                {
                    cell.image.image = [[ImageCache sharedImageCache] getImagefromCacheOrUrl:icon];



                }
            }`
```

and all working fine,Because i enabled paging i need to call the request to load the next set of values, like this

```
`- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if(indexPath.section==[sarray count]-1)
    {


             [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(loadingfeedcntents:) withObject:count];           
        }
}`
```

but here the problem is when i am scrolling the table view wrong images are assigned to the image views in the custom cell,Can anybody help me on this ?

Comment: sounds like the issue is with reusing cells in the tableview, can you please paste code where you create and return the cells for tableview.

Comment: @Preson can u check my edited question pls...

Comment: please add the `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` section of your code. `willDisplayCell` is called just before rendering the cell on screen, the contents are set in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Comment: @Preson thats the first one..

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably due the reuse of the cells. Probably what is happening is that you trigger an asynchronous request to download an image, while that is happening you scroll the table an that cell is reused so when the image finishes downloading that new cell gets the image instead of the one originally requested it.

I think you will have to find another way to do it or detach that request from the cell on `prepareForReuse`

Many people is recommending this class "[SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)" for that situation (although I haven't test it)

Answer (score 0):

I have been using SDWebImage for last 2 years and have used in 5 apps, Really easy and I would say it is the best way to load images in background with caching.

Please give a try. You will love it.
A nice tutorial is [here](http://iosmadesimple.blogspot.in/2013/04/lazy-image-loading.html).